# Fluentbit pump local file to splunk

Tags: splunk, fluentd, fluent-bit

I am trying to pump local file to splunk using fluentbit. The Splunk is currently https and secure.

I kept encountering error message of unexpected EOF, I am not sure what have I done wrongly in the fluent-bit.config file.
[image]

This is the general setting of the splunk

[image]

Below is the fluent-bit.config that I used with the fluent-bit.exe..

```
[INPUT]
    Name tail
    Tag taglog
    Path C:\*.json

[OUTPUT]
    Name splunk
    Match *
    Host localhost
    Port 443
    Splunk_Token <The HTTP Event Collector token generated in Splunk Web>
    TLS On
    TLS.Verify On
    http_user <The username login to Splunk Web>
    http_passwd <The password used to login to Splunk Web>
    splunk_send_raw On
```

when i set the "TLS.Verify" to Off, it will have 303 http status code
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to the web port. Instead you must send it to the management port. (I think it's 8089 by default, but you should confirm in your splunk settings)